# Choose the universe of keys

Tags: hash, hashtable, universal-hashing

I need to hash a sequence **S** of numbers of length **n^2** where each number is a sum of two numbers each of them is an element on one of the sequences: `{x_1,..., x_n},{y_1,..., y_n}`.

I am using universal hashing so the question is how do I find the universe of keys U, if there are infinitely many possibilities for members of S.